# haskell: output non-ascii characters

Tags: windows, haskell, non-ascii-characters

I'd like to output non-ascii characters in WinGHCi, but this is what I get:

```
Prelude> "δ"
"\948"
Prelude> putStr "\948"
*** Exception: <stdout>: hPutChar: invalid argument (character is not in the code page)
```

I am using WinGHCi 7.0.3 on windows xp. 
What do I have to do so that WinGHCi prints a nice little delta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on OSX!

```
Prelude> putStrLn "\948"
δ
```

Sounds like this is a windows problem with nothing to do with haskell...

Comment: How's this not a Haskell problem? Surely GHCi should be able to interface with its underlying platform correctly. Other programs somehow manage this incredible feat.

Comment: I guess this doesn't work becuase of my current codepage. It's just that I don't know how to change it, or better: how to make GHCi use the new codepage. chcp commands don't solve the problem.

Comment: GHCi is giving the character to windows, and windows is complaining that it doesn't know how to deal with it since it is not in the current codepage.  GHCi can't magically pick a codepage that does have a mapping for that character.  At best, there should be a way to call the [SetConsoleOutputCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686036(v=vs.85).aspx) function via the FFI, but it would be up to you to make the call, not GHCi.

Comment: What is the FFl? And how do I call this function?

Comment: The Foreign Function Interface, a way for haskell code to call functions written in other languages.  It is documented [here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1490008).  There is a wiki page [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foreign_Function_Interface).  I have never used it.  You could post a new question.

Comment: OK, you need [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/Win32-2.2.1.0/).  Check out `System.Win32.Console.setConsoleOutputCP`

Comment: thx, now I only need to find the codepage which supports all the characters I want to have.

Comment: Also works perfectly fine in Linux. Off course **it is** a typical Windows problem. Because http://www.utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Has this bug been reported?

Answer (score 1):

This is a WinGHCI bug. Use GHCI (the console, non-GUI version).

**UPD**: this is apparently not entirely correct (works for me with Greek letters and not e.g. Cyrillic).

Comment: What is your console code page (the `chcp` command)? I have 437 and it works.

Comment: I have CP 850, but I cannot change it. I typed     chcp 437    into my console but it always stays CP 850. If I set my stdout to utf8, then ghci prints some strange characters, but not a delta.

Comment: @Ingo: for me neither, also on W7.

Comment: @Ingo Yay chcp 65001 worked in Cygwin. You should add it as an answer.